# How find all possible functions? (Putnam problem)

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

Find all positive continuous functions, $0 \le x \le 1$, such that:

$$\int\limits_0^1 f(x)\ dx = 1$$

All $g^\prime (x)$ such that $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$ is a possible answer.

I found infinite functions that are correct but I'm not sure what the problem refer in "Find all". How I'm suppose to develop the answer to fix it?

One of the $f(x)$ I found was $f(x) = (n + 1) x^n$ with $n$ being any natural number but I know it doesn't cover all possible functions.

How I find all of such functions?

Comment: What year of the Putnam was this question from? It seems as if there should be more information

Comment: If $g$ is ANY positive function, then there exists a constant $C$ such that $f=Cg$ is a solution. $C=\frac{1}{\int_0^1 g(t) dt}$. It follows that the number of solutions is uncountable.

Comment: I think the integral description is as good as you are going to get unless there are further constraints.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be **part** of Putnam 1967 (A2):

**Problem:** [Putnam, 1967, A2] Find all positive continuous functions, $0 \leq x \leq 1$ , such that:
$$\int_0^1 f(x)dx =1 \\
\int_0^1 xf(x) dx =\alpha \\
\int_0^1 x^2 f(x) dx =\alpha^2$$

It is easy to argue that any such function would satisfy $\int_0^1 f(x) (\alpha -x)^2dx =0$, and that there is no such function.

**P.S.** Sometimes solving the entire problem is much easier than solving half of it.

Comment: I tried to attack the problem myself before looking at your solution but no success... is there some motivation for why we looked at $\int_0^1 f(x) (\alpha -x)^2dx =0$? Or is there some indication from beforehand that no such function exists, and then we look for such a way to prove it?

Comment: @Ovi I just realized that you can multiply the RHS by $\int_0^1 f(t) dx$ to make things symmetric. From there, I think it becomes natural to create a perfect square.